# WPF - How to detect if mouse has stopped moving

Tags: wpf

In a WPF application, how can you detect if the mouse pointer has stopped moving? 
I have a canvas and there is a circle(Ellipse) inside. User can move the mouse over the circle. I want see if the mouse is moving over the circle or it has stopped moving? MouseEnter even of the Ellipse object won't help cos it would be fired even if the mouse is not stopped over the Ellipse.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rukshan

Comment: I don't get it?! What do you want to achieve with that behavior? And how do you define "stopped"? Is it a timespan in where the mouse coords won't change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at the [ToolTipOpening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltipopening.aspx) event, you can use it as a marker of the mouse stopped on your element.